# WebAudio: Is there a way to determine if a node is connected to another?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

```
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

var oscillator = context.createOscillator();

oscillator.type = 'sine';
oscillator.frequency.value = 440;
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.start();
```

in the WebAudio API is there a way to check what nodes are connected to another, for example checking to see what nodes are connected to `context.destination` in the example above

or vice-versa, checking to see what nodes a particular node is connected to, for example checking to see what nodes `oscillator` is connected to in the example above

alternatively, is there some way to get information on a particular audio context's graph? similar to the way the Firefox Dev Console's WebAudio Context Visualizer does?

Comment: Bit of a late comment but one solution here is to write a connection manager to track this information, and using it to proxy functions like `.connect` (as well as things like `stop` or setting ramp values so you manually schedule start/finish events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Audio has no builtin way to determine this.

If you are using Chrome, you can try out https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-audio-inspector/cmhomipkklckpomafalojobppmmidlgl?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon which similar to Firefox's Web Audio visualizer.